# Remove header & footer in WordPress depends on domain & assign new one

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress strategy is through domain mapping. For that reason I have multiple domains in one wordpress database (it's not WordPress multisite, it's just WordPress mapping domains).
I am looking through functions.php to create a function that remove from the domains  the header & footer ( i don't want to remove header & footer in my main domain).

I have also created this function which will help you to understand exactly what i want as it's similar.
As you can see in this code it change the home page depends on the domain.
In my case I want to remove the  header & footer and assign  new depend on the domains. I prefer to load a header & footer from elementor depending on the domain

```
add_filter('pre_option_page_on_front', function($page_id) {
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'www.domain1.com' :
    case 'domain1.com' :
        return $page_id; // Default
    case 'domain2.com' :
    case 'domain2.com' :
        return 15683; // Override
         case 'domain3.com' :
    case 'domain3.com' :
        return 15683; // Override
    default :
        exit; // We're not handling requests for this domain
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Elementor Developers](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/php/) provides some hooks, but doesn't seem to be very comprehensive and doesn't have enough to achieve your purpose.

So, if you're using Elementor, you could create all the three header layouts within the same Elementor header template. Give each of them a different class name. Then you can add a show/hide CSS class to them depending on the domain.